# Dupont connector for 5A

Tags: pcb, motor, connector, high-current

I have to do a connector adapter, that has to handle 5A current, from a pwm motor driving circuit(power mosfet), to the motor.
I have not found the current rating for dupont connectors

[image]

It is possibile to use them for a prototype connection or it is dangerous?
Thanks

Comment: It's totally fine to use them for prototype, just be aware that they can introduce a voltage drop and heat up in the worst case. To be safe, you can double or triple the number of connections – use two or three wires in parallel instead of each single wire.

Answer (score 3):

I think those cables are 26AWG (American wire gauge).

You can use an online calculator to get the AWG you need, depending the Voltage, Amperage and length.

http://www.solar-wind.co.uk/cable-sizing-DC-cables.html

Comment: I don't quite understand how wire current rating and connector current rating are related. You could crimp a 22 AWG wire into Dupont pins, but that wouldn't make the pins compatible with 5A.

Comment: The point is that for the thin ~26 AWG wires shown in the photo, it's the wire that's going to limit safe current before the connector will. IMHO having a wire slightly more capable than the connector is preferable, as strands may break internally over time if things are being plugged/unplugged, allowing a longer useful lifespan.

Answer (score 3):

Buy your connectors from a supplier which provides the specs for it, then you'll know the current rating. Example: [Dupont 2.54 mm pitch connector](http://www.aruielectronics.com/en/displayproduct.html?proID=528761), rated for 3A AC or DC. Using no-name parts without any specs is asking for all kinds of surprises.

BTW, I have never seen Dupont connectors rated for more than 3A. I know it's impossible to prove a negative, but it's very unlikely the pins you've got can handle 5A.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb you can pull 3A through such a connector. It is very hard to find current ratings for 0.1"/2.54mm dupont connectors in most datasheets, some do specify one though, eg: http://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0901200121_PCB_HEADERS.pdf

However I have certainly seen poor examples of these connectors, usually the pins, which I would not rely on for even 3A.

To address your question "is it dangerous", you could certainly try this as a prototype, but you should never leave the device unattended. You may also see lower current consumption in such a prototype compared to the final design due to the extra resistance in the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the connector I have
found are only 2.5Amp, but for safety it should be derated a bit depending how much overall power is going through it.